# Translating Conditional Formatting to VBA codes

Tags: vba, excel

I have to apply two conditional formatting to my data in a sheet called "Report" (num of rows are not fixed). I can do these via the "Manage Rules" option via conditional formatting. So I tried to record macro but unfortunately I don't see any codes recorded.

Conditional Formatting 1:

```
 =$F5="NH Orientation" , then Color (242,220,219)
```

Conditional Formatting 2:

```
=OR($O4<4,$G4="Elective"), then color (242,220,219)
```

Post which I will cut and paste the colored cells in row 2 and below in another sheet called "Removed"

I want to have these conditions in macro in my excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You decide how to tweak but the following are the main elements:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddRules()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")   ' change

    Dim rule1 As FormatCondition
    Dim rule2 As FormatCondition

    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = GetLastRow(ws, 1)

    If lastRow < 4 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid number of rows"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With ws.Range("A4:V" & lastRow)

        .FormatConditions.Delete

        Set rule1 = .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
                                          Formula1:="=$F5=""NH Orientation""")
        rule1.StopIfTrue = True 'Change as required

        Set rule2 = .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
                                          Formula1:="=OR($O4<4,$G4=""Elective"")")
        Dim i As Long

        For i = 1 To 2

            With .FormatConditions(i)

                With .Interior
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = RGB(242, 220, 219)
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With

            End With

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long

    With ws

       GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row

    End With

End Function
```

Reference:

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/formatconditions-add-method-excel

Comment: Hi, would like to understand why range is from A1-A4? Also, what does 
".formatcondition.delete" means?

Comment: I needed to choose a range to apply this formula to so I randomly chose that range. You would change this as appropriate. The .Delete bit is to get rid of any existing conditional formatting rules before I add the two specified ones. These also are both applied with stop when True. The main elements of what you need should all be there.

Comment: @QHarr Nice :) what time is it there ?

Comment: 07:00 in the morning. Where you are?

Comment: shamie - did that make sense?

Comment: Understood. My data is from row 4 onwards, whereby the header for these data is from A3:V3. the number of rows which contains the data can vary. Hence I was wondering if can have a formula to detect the last row with information and apply the conditional formatting to the relevant rows, starting from the last row with data up to row 3.

Comment: SO you are trying to apply to A3:V & lastRow ?

Comment: A4:V4 to last row, since row 3 is the header.

Comment: I am using column A to determine last row in edit. You can specify which column by changing the 1 in GetLastRow(ws,1) to the column number of your choice.

Comment: If you want to see last row in a different way have a look at the options here https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm   Let me know how that goes.

Comment: can we do it without the function? What i need it to do is to apply the conditional formatting from  row four to last row, with column being a-v.

Comment: what do you mean? The above does that.

Comment: Can we do it without the public function portion? i am not sure why the above doesnt work, nothing happens when i run the code, not even error message

Comment: Im getting invalid num of rows as there are no values in rows 1-3, row 4 is the header. so row 5 and below are those with data

Comment: i thought row 3 was the header? The function finds the last row of the column you specify for the sheet you specify. So is ws the correct sheet and 1 is column A should be correct. It comes up from the bottom of the page so doesn't matter there is nothing in rows 1-3. If you put STOP  before   .FormatConditions.Delete     , what is the value of lastRow in the locals window?

Comment: i tried to put stop before  .formatconditions.delete, and it did not work still. i removed it and it worked. will removing that line cause any issues?

Comment: However, it does not highlight accurately.

First Condition:
If the data (row 4 onwards) has "NH Orientation" in Column F = then highlight

Second Condition:
If the data has (row 4 onwards) "Elective" in Column G and value<4 in Column O, then highlight

Comment: Do you have a sample file (xlsx without any code in or sensitive data)? Might be quicker to simply debug your issue that way.

Comment: Also, you specified OR not AND in your original formula.

Comment: This Formula1:="=AND($O4<4,$G4=""Elective"")")  gives a very different result.

Comment: I tried to separate the formulas out and color them separately. I used different colours so that i can see which one is working. Also changed to AND instead of OR. So Rule 2 is working fine right now. Still trying to work on Rule 1.

Answer (score 0):

I modified as below and it is working now. Please advise if this can be improved.

```
Sub AddRules()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Report")

Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = GetLastRow(ws, 1)

If lastRow < 4 Then
    MsgBox "Invalid number of rows"
    Exit Sub
End If

With ws.Range("A4:V" & lastRow)

    .FormatConditions.Delete

    Set rule1 = .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
                                      Formula1:="=$F4=""NH Orientation""")
        With rule1
            .Interior.Color = RGB(242, 250, 219)
        End With

End With

With ws.Range("A4:V" & lastRow)

    Set rule2 = .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression,Formula1:="=AND($O4<4,$G4=""Elective"")")
        With rule2
            .Interior.Color = RGB(242, 210, 219)
        End With

End With

End Sub

Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long

With ws

   GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row

End With

End Function
```

Comment: what is this wsasrreport    ?   Are you applying to different sheets the conditional formatting?

Comment: I have amended that part back, the above is the final one.

Comment: that is basically my answer except 1) You have changed F5 (which it is in the question) to F4 and 2) You have removed the rule1.StopIfTrue = True  which I said you would need to amend as required. Pretty sure I answered your question. You have now multiplied the number of lines of code. Here is info on StopIfTrue https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/formatcondition-stopiftrue-property-excel

Comment: Yes @QHarr - i made slight changes to the code you gave and it is working now. thank you!